# Strategies for debugging a runtime Java crash that runs correctly in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, runtime-error

Sorry in advance. This is a really vague question because I have no idea whatsoever what is going on. I have a Java Swing GUI desktop app that I wrote in NetBeans. While inside of NetBeans, the app works fine and passes all of the tests that I have thrown at it. I've been developing this app over the past several months, deploying it at various phases of its development.

Yesterday, I finished adding and testing some new functionality. I built the application and put it on another computer. I then went to run the program (outside of NetBeans) straight from the jar file. While in the new areas (JDialog boxes), the program crashes. Since I am not in an IDE, I have no feedback to see what is wrong.

The only thing that I can think of (and this is lame) is that I added some switch statements that switch on strings, which I know to new to 1.7. I was previously developing in 1.6. Otherwise, I can think of no reason that the program should work flawlessly inside the IDE, but crash outside of it.

Can anyone offer any suggestions for how I should approach this? I'm at a complete loss.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add some logging.

Comment: Run the Jar from the command line so any exceptions show (presuming they are not caught & ignored in the code).

Answer (score 1):

The next debugging step for you is reducing the size of your program until it doesn't crash, then seeing what change you made worked.  That should either make the answer obvious or give you a good question to post on SO.

Your idea that it might have to do with switch statements tells you to try:

- removing them
- removing and compiling on JDK 6 and see if it works

Those are reasonable ways to reduce your program size to see if you can make it run.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there might be some tools to assist with this, but looks like I'll have to do it the old fashioned way (meaning I'll have to put in some work). Thanks again!

Comment: The other answer is a good suggestion.  But typically the IDE is the tool soooo yeah, this one is trickier.  And per the comment if an exception happens you really should be catching it and logging it persistently.  What happens if it runs fine in NetBeans, fine in production, then hours later breaks in production?  That is impossible to debug without logs.

Answer (score 1):

I would start from collecting a crash dump data.
If you run the UI on windows you could use [DrWatson](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/15/capturing-application-crash-dumps.aspx)

If you run the UI in Linux , By default the heap dump is created in a file called java_pidpid.hprof in the working directory of the VM. unless you specify the path yourself by adding this `-XX:HeapDumpPath= option`  to your UI java options.

Comment: Good to know. I'm running in Windows, but maybe I'll download the JRE on my Linux VM and see what that show. Thanks!